# Can I browse windows 7 libraries from the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, libraries

If I am at a Windows 7 command prompt is there any way that I can navigate to one of my libraries?

e.g. something like

```
cd libraries:\code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Windows 7 Libraries are currently supported through GUI console only.

Comment: can you offer a reference/explanation?  I find this disturbing!

Answer (score 6):

I believe the above response is quite simply incorrect. Below is a command line utility compiled by grimadmin based on MSDN code for just such purposes predating the aforementioned response. I should mention however that it doesn't support anything as convenient as a cd into a library though.

http://www.grimadmin.com/filemgmt/index.php?id=5

Comment: nice. also, for ms. powershell: http://windowslibrariespsh.codeplex.com/ (haven't tried myself)