# Doing a dir or ls for a windows library abstraction?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cygwin, shared-libraries

We all know `dir` and if you have cygwin `ls`. I am wondering how could I use either of these commands for a windows library abstraction. For example, my music library points to `C:\users\me\music` and `c:\users\public\music` I try to do `dir \libraries\music` hoping to get contents for both, but I get:

```
C:\>dir \libraries\pictures
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your answer is here:
http://superuser.com/questions/203639/can-i-browse-windows-7-libraries-from-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Officially you can't use the command prompt to browse libraries.

However a 3rd party tool appears to let you somewhat access libraries from the command prompt, but doesn't appear to let you just "cd" into one. You may like to try it though:

http://www.grimadmin.com/filemgmt/index.php?id=5