# Why can't I "open command window here" inside a Library?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, cmd.exe

I'm talking about the extra options you get with `left Shift + right click`.

If you can open a cmd window elsewhere, then `cd` to a library directory, why can't you open the directory in a library?

I know that you can do some registry changes, to change this, but I'm just curious as to why this functionality doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/203639/can-i-browse-windows-7-libraries-from-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add several locations to a library; the library forms a single consistent view over all these locations.  Therefore, when you say open command prompt "here", potentially "here" actually refers to several places.  I suppose Windows could open a command prompt in every one of them but that probably isn't helpful.

If you Shift+Right Click an actual folder inside a Library, you will get the option to open a command prompt.  Similarly, if you expand the Library in the tree view and Shift-Right Click an actual folder the option exists.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple workaround for this.

Usually we do not need libraries, but we get trapped into one because the "Documents" command on Windows' main menu links to a library.
In facts, if you access Documents this way you'll notice that in the address bar there's "Libraries\Documents".

Normally, however, we just need to access ***our very own*** Documents folder, which is normally named "C:\users\<username>\Documents". This is a single physical path, so the "Command Prompt Here" will pop up on Shift+RMB.

You can navigate to "C:\users\<username>" by Windows Explorer: there you'll find your physical "Documents" directory. **Hodling Alt**, drag and drop it onto your Desktop to create a link to it.

Next time (instead of selecting the "Documents" entry on Windows main menu) just double-click the previously created link, and here you go: you've just accessed a **physical path**. Welcome back, "Command Prompt Here"!

Answer (score 0):

Because a library does not exist at a physical file path, but a meta-path (a path that refers to one or more paths indirectly).

cmd is a much older construct, so it makes sense that it requires a physical path to start in. without it, it has no context for commands. in the case of libraries, since they may consist of 0-many paths, the system can't decide which path the shell should display as prompt and to execute commands from.

Answer (score 0):

While other provides explanation, here is workaround for open cmd (maybe without admin right).

Assume only single folder inside that Library.

1. In File Explorer, click the address bar to select it (or press
   Alt+D).
2. Type `cmd` into the address bar and hit Enter to open the Command
   Prompt with the path of the current folder

If someone know how to open cmd with admin right inside Library, please share.