# Running a custom batch file on keyboard shortcut in current directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, batch-file

I'm developing lot of small .esb services recently and I'm pretty tired of doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd> to open `cmd`in current directory then typing `mvn clean install`.

What is the easiest way to run simple `.bat` file like:

**cleanInstall.bat:**

```
mvn clean install
```

on current directory when user will press a some simple shortcut e.g.: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

I have already read this thread: [How can I open a command prompt in current folder with a keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-can-i-open-a-command-prompt-in-current-folder-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)
However I'm wondering do I need to use 3rd party software?

I'm using Windows 7 Polish version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit your batch file to `cd /D "%1"` before running `mvn`.
2. In [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/205368/269989) to the question you linked, change the lines at the bottom so that `Run,  cmd /K cd /D "%full_path%"` is replaced with `Run,  mvnCleanInstall.bat "%full_path%"` (or whatever your batch file is called).
3. Install autohotkey and the modified script per the comments to [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/205368/269989).
4. Enjoy!

(Edited-original answer below)

Other options: Classic Shell will let you create toolbar buttons in Explorer windows that run programs in the directory that window is showing.

Alternatively, you could create a shortcut to your bat file and name the shortcut "c" or something else short.  Then you could type `c` in the address bar of an Explorer window and hit Enter to run the bat in the open folder.  ([Source](https://superuser.com/a/946863/269989))

Comment: 2nd option can be pretty nice workaround my problem. I will try it, HOWEVER in my version of windows non Alt+D nor Alt+E are focusing a address at address bar field. There is a uncomfortable F4 button which brings a cursor to the end of address, then i need to focus all with Ctrl+A then enter my command. Too many unnessery actions. Do you know maybe any other method to focus address bar?

Comment: Naming `.bat` file like 'c' and putting into System32 works pretty well, however i need to find simple method to focus and clear address bar. Autohotkey option works aswell, but i will give a try to do it without other software.

Comment: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Desktop-PC-Questions/quot-Alt-S-quot-key-shortcut/td-p/74954 suggests maybe some other program is grabbing alt+d or +e - maybe check that?  Does the behaviour change depending on what keyboard input language you have selected?