# Open Command Prompt in Folder via Rightclick

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10

So I've bought a Win10 laptop and I find myself using the command prompt frequently - in different folders. At first, I just put 1-line batch scripts everywhere to start the Prompt in that folder, but it was repetetive and not really worth it too much.

I remember (perhaps falsely) that I could right-click on a folder and an option "Open Command Prompt in This Folder" would appear. Is there a way to have that available in Windows 10?

Comment: The option is still there. You just have to hold **shift** while you right click on a folder. Alternatively, you can try the answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/946860/how-to-open-windows-cmd-so-that-it-starts-in-the-current-folder/946863#946863)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tutorial on http://www.winbeta.org/news/open-command-prompt-specific-windows-10-file-directory, you can just open the directory you want through Explorer, then in the File dropdown menu you'll find an option to open a command window in that location.

From the comments, you should also be able to Shift + Right Click a directory icon, and will see the option "Open command window here".

Comment: This should be on every Windows help page. Thanks so much!